# Scroll percentage for a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, scrollbar, percentage

```js
const rightSide = document.querySelector("#rightSide");

let scrollPercentage = () => {
  let h = document.documentElement;
  let st = h.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  let sh = h.scrollHeight || document.body.scrollHeight;
  let percent = st / (sh - h.clientHeight) * 100;
  console.log(percent);
}

rightSide.onscroll = scrollPercentage;
```

```css
.right-side {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.top-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.bot-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-side" id="rightSide">
  <div id="top-page" class="top-page"></div>
  <div id="bot-page" class="bot-page"></div>
</div>
```

I'm making a website and I want to get the scroll percentage of a div. I've used Tyler Pott's video on YouTube https://youtu.be/-FJSedZAers and he does that to the whole page (using the body). And this is my code:

```
 const rightSide = document.querySelector("#rightSide")

  let scrollPercentage = () => {
    let h = document.documentElement;
    let st = h.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    let sh = h.scrollHeight || document.body.scrollHeight;

    let percent = st / (sh - h.clientHeight) * 100;
    console.log(percent);
  }

  rightSide.onscroll = scrollPercentage;
```

When I run this, the console just outputs "NaN" which is to be expected. I am not sure what I should do in order to transfer that code onto the divs. I've tried to use things like

```
  const topPage = document.querySelector("#top-page");
```

And then add  topPage instead of the body in `document.body.scrollTop` etc. but that obviously doesn't work.

This is sort of what the HTML looks like, and the top page has a width and height of the rightSide div and the bottom page has the same width but a minimum height of the rightSide div.

```
 <div class="right-side" id="rightSide">
  <div id="top-page" class="top-page"></div>
  <div id="bot-page" class="bot-page"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can click [edit], then the `[<>]` snippet editor to make a [mcve]

Comment: I hope I've done it correctly. Let me know if it works.

Comment: sh - h.clientHeight is 0, you cannot divide by 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this I knew that I had to understand the values assigned to the variables in order to make the equation simpler.

So, a quick search for documentElement led me to this answer:

"documentElement returns the Element that is the root element of the document (for example, the  element for HTML documents)"

Then, I realised that maybe that is the issue and it was. I assigned rightSide to h and that's all that was needed.

`let h = rightSide;`

Not sure if this is fully correct, sometimes at the end of the scroll you can get 100.05 or more, but I didn't need the precise number. Hope this helps.